# Adding pagination to WP_Query

Tags: loop, pagination

I've got the following loop (this is on a `single` page, not the `index.php`):

```
$top_meta_cat_args =
    array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'top-radio',
    'meta_value' => 'top-yes',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

And it works perfectly. However, when I add code to take the user to the next page, nothing happens:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_next_posts_page_link();  ?>" class="btn-ar"> more articles</a>
```

This adds to the current URL: `&paged=3`, but the content is still the same.

I've also tried removing the `echo`, but nothing happens. [The Codex explains about adding pagination](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query). But I am unsure how to use this with the associative array that I exampled above.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Give something like this a whirl:

```
<?php
// Get header
get_header(); ?>

<?php // Begin loop
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

$args = array (
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'paged' => $paged
); 

query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>


<article>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
<p class="time"><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y'); ?></p>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><?php previous_posts_link('< previous page', 0); ?></li>
</li><?php next_posts_link('next page >', 0); ?></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<?php else: endif; ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that just seems to take me back to the homepage again. I've also tried creating `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` and adding it to the `query: ` 'paged' => $paged``, but no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't tested my last answer. Give the new code that I've added a try. Works this end.

Comment: Sorry — nope. Still just takes me to the index page. Here is a pastebin of the current page: http://pastebin.com/k90WJeA5. Could it be because I have multiple WP_Query's on different pages?

Comment: I'm a bit of a WP newbie, so I'm not 100% sure if it's down to your other queries. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Try it and it might work for you too.

```
    $paged = (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
        $args = array(
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' =>9,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'

        );


      $posts = query_posts($args); 

 <?php 
    global $post;
    if ( ! empty($posts) ) :
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);  
?>




      <a title="<?php echo ''.get_the_title(); ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">



<?php }
else : ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<<?php echo get_next_posts_link(); ?></div>
<?php echo get_previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Nope, it still takes me to the homepage for some reason. When I installed the `wp-pagenavi` plugin, it said there were over 1000 next pages — there should be 3 (and it still didn't work). Could it be because I've got multiple WP_Querys, and it's taking them all into account?

Comment: Try the code with one query on a page and see if it works. Also, try deactivating your `wp-pagenavi` plugin and run this code.

Comment: Sorry, there's only one WP_Query to a page, it's just I have many throughout the site. I disabled the plugin and tried again, but no luck. For what it's worth, it is generating the URL: `http://fashion-detail.dev/?cat=4&paged=2` but no taking me anywhere.

Comment: Well then it's not an issue of `wp_query`